# Pandas : Concat rows of a dataframe with same index to form custom string in pairs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-apply, python-applymap

Say I have a dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA' : ['ABC', 'JKL', 'STU', '123'],
                   'colB' : ['DEF', 'MNO', 'VWX', '456'],
                   'colC' : ['GHI', 'PQR', 'YZ', '789'],}, index = [0,0,1,1])
```

```
   colA colB colC
0  ABC   DEF  GHI 
0  JKL   MNO  PQR
1  STU   VWX   YZ
1  123   456  789
```

Its guranteed that every pair will have the same index, so we would like the end result to be :

```
     colA        colB       colC
0  ABC_JKL_0   DEF_MNO_0  GHI_PQR_0 
1  STU_123_1   VWX_456_1   YZ_789_1
```

where the suffix `_number` is the index of that group.

I tried doing this by iterating through rows but that's taking a lot of time.
I was thinking of something like `.groupby(level=0)` but can't figure out the next `aggregation apply` part

Comment: Try: `df_out=df.groupby(level=0).agg('_'.join)` to start.

Comment: yeah tried that, stuck there!

Comment: `df_out=df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: '_'.join(x)+'_'+str(x.index[0]))`

Comment: @ScottBoston Is it possible to apply multiple function on aggregate? like say first list then tuple, obviously no one would want that but just thinking if multiple function could be applied or not

Comment: @ScottBoston please add that as answer, ll accept that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can try something like this using .agg and a lambda function or you can add it into the dataframe after the groupby:

```
df_out=df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: '_'.join(x)+'_'+str(x.index[0]))
```

Output:

```
        colA       colB       colC
0  ABC_JKL_0  DEF_MNO_0  GHI_pQR_0
1  STU_123_1  VWX_456_1   YZ_789_1
```

Or

```
df_out=df.groupby(level=0).agg('_'.join)
df_out = df_out.add('_'+df_out.index.to_series().astype(str), axis=0)
print(df_out)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: f"{'_'.join(x)}_{x.index[0]}")
```

Output:

```
        colA       colB       colC
0  ABC_JKL_0  DEF_MNO_0  GHI_PQR_0
1  STU_123_1  VWX_456_1   YZ_789_1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg('_'.join).transform(lambda x:x+'_'+str(x.index[0]))
```